# Minkowski as a Quotient Space

Tags: special-relativity, symmetry, group-theory, lorentz-symmetry, poincare-symmetry

I've read many times, in many articles or books that one can obtain the four dimensional Minkowski space $\mathbb{M}^4$ as the quotient space 
$$
ISO(3,1)/SO(3,1), 
$$
and equivalently de Sitter and Anti-de Sitter can be seen as $SO(4,1)/SO(3,1)$ and $SO(3,2)/SO(3,1)$, respectively. I.e. we can see these manifolds by taking their symmetry Lie group and quotienting by the normal Lorentz subgroup $SO(3,1)$.

This construction seems intuitive but I cannot find a decent reference where these steps are taken with a little more care, I don't mean  "Math-rigour" but just "Theoretical Physics-rigour": I would like to see $\mathbb{M}^4$ emerging from explicit group theoretical calculations (I'm familiar with group actions, orbits and all that).

Can anyone provide a nice and specific explanation without referencing to general theorems but starting from general grounds? Or just a good, not too mathy but still clear, reference?

Comment: This is just an application of the general theorem that, when given a transitive group action of a Lie group, the quotient of the Lie group by the stabilizer of a point is a manifold. Alternatively, you can think of the spaces you act on as being manifolds a priori, and obtain an equivariant diffeomorphism between $G/H$ and $M$, where $G$ is the Lie group, $H$ is the stabilizer of a point and $M$ is the manifold acted upon. The proof of this theorem is not easy; it relies on the closed subgroup theorem and related machinery.

Comment: Thank you for the comment but as I wrote I'd be more satisfied by an explicit calculation for the specific case I mentioned above, without quoting general theorems.

Comment: You can work out for yourself why $SO(3,1)$ is the stabilizer of a point in Minkowski space, probably.

Comment: @Danu can you provide someplace to read these things? Thanks

Comment: @bgr95 I learned it from [here](http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~hamilton/gaugetheoryI/GaugeTheoryLecture.pdf).

Comment: Pick a point in Minkowski space and call it $X$.  Map $ISO(3,1)/SO(3,1)$ by mapping the class of $\phi\in ISO(3,1)$ to the point $\phi(X)$.  Check that this is well-defined, one-one and onto.  If you're slightly more ambitious, check that it's also continuous in both directions.

Comment: Since you ask for a reference, try the old paper by E. Ivanov and J. Niederle, Phys. Rev. D 25 (1982) 976. They construct GR as an ISO(3,1) gauge theory on the ISO(3,1)/SO(3,1) coset space.

Comment: This is done explicitly for Minkowski space (and many others) in https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.00034